# Matching user-input text with a user-input regex in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, denial-of-service

I'm assuming that DoS is a possible issue when matching, on the backend in Node.js, arbitrary strings with arbitrary regexes with one of [JS's regex functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#:%7E:text=exec()%20and%20test()%20methods%20of%20RegExp%2C%20and%20with%20the%20match()%2C%20matchAll()%2C%20replace()%2C%20replaceAll()%2C%20search()%2C%20and%20split()%20methods%20of%20String). If the provided regex is simply invalid, the error thrown by the constructor can just be caught -- but I'm thinking it's possible that matching the string with the RegExp could become a significantly or even completely blocking operation, deliberately or accidentally by the creator of the regex and the string? If so, how exactly would this be caused, and how could it be mitigated?

Comment: maybe look at the user given input and do a check to see if the regex combination is suspicious before actually running the regex? or how about you **do whatever you're trying to do without allowing a client to run direct regex on your backend**

Comment: @TheBombSquad How exactly would you 'check if it's suspicious' though? And the latter isn't an option in my case since the client isn't a browser.

Comment: the latter can be an option if u rewire things that you don't have to be running regexes that the client gives u ;-;